# How to determine if a datetime object overlaps with an ical string?

Tags: python, icalendar

Suppose I have an ical string:

```
cal_str = """
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;TZID=America/New_York:20211019T000000
DTEND;TZID=America/New_York:20211019T235959
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=SU,MO,TU,WE,TH,FR,SA
X-STATE:convenience
END:VEVENT
"""
```

And a `datetime` object `datetime(2022, 11, 7, 4, 53, tzinfo=timezone.utc)`.

How can I confirm that the `datetime` object falls within the ical string? I've tried using `rules.between` but this `datetime`, which should overlap with the ical string, does not.

example code:

```
from dateutil import rrule
import pytz
from dateutil.tz import gettz
from icalendar.cal import Calendar
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone

cal_str = """
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;TZID=America/New_York:20211019T000000
DTEND;TZID=America/New_York:20211019T235959
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=SU,MO,TU,WE,TH,FR,SA
X-STATE:convenience
END:VEVENT
"""

def test_ical(target_time):
    ical = Calendar.from_ical(cal_str)
    start_time_dt = ical.get("DTSTART").dt
    tzinfo = gettz(str(start_time_dt.tzinfo))
    start_time_dt = start_time_dt.replace(tzinfo=None).replace(tzinfo=tzinfo)
    end_time_dt = ical["DTEND"].dt if ical.get("DTEND") else None

    irrule = ical.get("RRULE")
    recurring_rule = irrule.to_ical().decode('utf-8')
    rules = rrule.rruleset()
    first_rule = rrule.rrulestr(recurring_rule, dtstart=start_time_dt)
    rules.rrule(first_rule)
    event_delta = end_time_dt - start_time_dt if end_time_dt else timedelta(days=1)
    res = rules.between(target_time - event_delta, target_time + timedelta(minutes=1))
    return res

print(test_ical(datetime(2022, 11, 7, 4, 53, tzinfo=timezone.utc)))
print(test_ical(datetime(2022, 11, 9, 4, 53, tzinfo=timezone.utc)))
```

Comment: Why don't you parse the start and end times from the ical string and test if the target is in between?

Comment: can you give an example? my understanding is that this is a recurring rule and there is no start time/end time.

Comment: What is `rules.between` ? Do you have a [example] showing the code you tried?

Comment: @hc_dev i've added a reproducible example.

Comment: And why do you think that the given datetime should overlap with this ical string? The ical string contains start and end dates both in 2021 while the datetime object is in 2022.

Comment: The event is in 2021, the date in 2022. Did you mean to use `datetime(2021,` ?

Comment: Even if they did, the cal entry is for the single day 2021-10-19, so even 2021-11-07 is not going to overlap.

Comment: i've added a 2nd test for 2022 and you can see that returns returns a value. it is a recurring event.

Answer (score 0):

I would split your task/problem into 3 parts:

1. parse the ical entry to rrule and delta returned as tuple: `ical_to_rrule_delta()`
2. evaluate if there is an event for this rrule which contains the reference/target time-stamp: `datetime_in_rrule()`
3. helper function to show events generated from rrule: `event_list()`

I also adjusted the test-data (ical entry with 2 reference timestamps).

```
from icalendar.cal import Calendar  # https://icalendar.readthedocs.io/
from dateutil import rrule  # https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/
import pytz
from datetime import datetime

def ical_to_rrule_delta(cal_str):
    ical = Calendar.from_ical(cal_str)
    # dates
    start = ical.get("DTSTART").dt
    print(f"parsed start: {start} at TZ {start.tzinfo}")
    end = ical.get("DTEND").dt
    print(f"parsed end: {end} at TZ {end.tzinfo}")
    
    # recurrence rule
    rule = ical.get("RRULE")
    until = rule.get("UNTIL")[0]
    recurring_rule = rrule.rrule(
        freq=2, # not sure how to pass rule.get('FREQ')[0] (which is a str but int required)  
        dtstart=start, 
        until=until,
        byweekday=range(6), # not sure how to pass rule.get('BYDAY') (which is a list of str but list of int required) 
    ) 
    print(f"parsed rrule: {recurring_rule}")
    
    delta = end - start
    print(f"calculated delta: {delta}")

    return recurring_rule, delta


def event_list(rrule):
    events = list(rrule)
    print(f"events generated from fule: {events}")
    
    return events


def datetime_in_rrule(target, rule, delta):
    # verify if target inside an event's time-frame using delta
    #print(f"after={target}, before={target+delta}")
    res1 = rule.between(after=target, before=target+delta, inc=False)
    #print(f"after={target-delta}, before={target}")
    res2 = rule.between(after=target-delta, before=target, inc=False)
    
    return res1 or res2 



# Weekly from September 2, 09:00 to 11:00, until December 24, 1997:
cal_str = """
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;TZID=America/New_York:19970902T090000
DTEND;TZID=America/New_York:19970902T110000
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=SU,MO,TU,WE,TH,FR,SA;UNTIL=19971224T000000Z
X-STATE:convenience
END:VEVENT
"""

(rule, delta) = ical_to_rrule_delta(cal_str)

tz_NY = pytz.timezone('America/New_York')
ref_in = datetime(1997, 9, 10, 9, 30, tzinfo=tz_NY)
print(f"ref_in {ref_in} is: {datetime_in_rrule(ref_in, rule, delta)}")
ref_out = datetime(2022, 11, 9, 4, 53, tzinfo=tz_NY)
print(f"ref_out {ref_out} is: {datetime_in_rrule(ref_out, rule, delta)}")
```

Output:

```
parsed start: 1997-09-02 09:00:00-04:00 at TZ America/New_York
parsed end: 1997-09-02 11:00:00-04:00 at TZ America/New_York
parsed rrule: DTSTART:19970902T090000
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=19971224T000000;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR,SA
calculated delta: 2:00:00
ref_in 1997-09-10 09:30:00-04:56 is: [datetime.datetime(1997, 9, 10, 9, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'America/New_York' EDT-1 day, 20:00:00 DST>)]
ref_out 2022-11-09 04:53:00-04:56 is: []
```

Note: The parsing to rrule needs to be improved. Currently the frequency and weekdays are not mapped from ical, but set as constants.